# 500 error with insertData on CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage

I am trying to create a survey landing page in cloudpages that will pull data into an existing data extension with AMPscript, but I am getting a 500 server error when the AMPscript is in. I am working with the salesforce team and they said that the error is in the insertData line, but I am unable to identify it. Can you see anything in this code that might be causing the error? I am very new to salesforce and coding, so sorry if it is obvious but could not find any fixes online that helped. Thank you!

```
%%[
set @firstname = RequestParameter("First Name")
set @lastname = RequestParameter("Last Name")
set @email = RequestParameter("Email")
set @phonenumber = RequestParameter("Phone Number")
set @zipcode = RequestParameter("Zip Code")
set @age = RequestParameter("Age")
insertData("DATA EXTENSION","First Name",@firstname,"Last Name", @lastname, "Email", @email, "Phone Number", @phonenumber, "Zip Code", @zipcode, "Age", @age",)
]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function AMPscript function - `InsertData` has 3 issues:

1. You did not set a variable for it;
2. At the very end you have double-quotes after the `@age` variable;
3. Also at the very end, after the `@age` variable you have a comma but there are no more additional attributes and values specified.

Thus, your function should look like this -

```
SET @insertData = InsertData("DATA EXTENSION", "First Name", @firstname, "Last Name", 
 @lastname, "Email", @email, "Phone Number", @phonenumber, "Zip Code", @zipcode, "Age", @age)
```

You can review how to properly set up the function [here](https://ampscript.guide/insertdata/).

Comment: Thank you Niko ! Unfortunately, that still gives me a 500 error when I try to publish the page.

Comment: I assume Data Extension's name is correct, then maybe when you are trying to insert the data into the DE, you are exceeding the field's length and/or generally cannot pass the validation for specific Data Type fields for example, "Email Address". The syntax of your `RequestParameter` and my `InsertData` functions are correct at this point.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think field length is the issue. Do you know how I can troubleshoot validation for data type fields?

Comment: Review this [article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/09/debugging-ampscript/) to troubleshoot the error you have. Btw, also consider Primary Key violations and fields that are non-nullable and that are skipped in your `InsertData` Function.

Comment: Thank you, this is the message I received in return: `InsertData Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in a non batch context.\r\n Function: InsertData(\"DATA EXTENSION\", \"FirstName\", @FirstName, \"LastName\", \r\n @LastName, \"Email\", @Email, \"PhoneNumber\", @PhoneNumber, \"ZipCode\", @ZipCode)\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR\r\n - from OMMCommon\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}`

Comment: Are you trying to insert data into DE called “DATA EXTENSION”, looks like you forgot to change it. If that is not the case just go and check yourself really carefully if all field names are matched exactly as you have them in the function, if your DE have PK —> check if the same PK already exists, check non-nullable fields. I do not have a vision over all related assets that you have, but from AMPscript syntax point of view the function is correct. Last checks could only be done by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the new Web Studio that's based on content builder, then you don't want to use InsertData, instead you need to use InsertDE, then should fix the 500 error it is experiencing right now.